# VBA refining range

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to draw data from a separate sheet and put it into a corresponding cell if the conditions are met.  My code works, but it is not efficient.  I do not know how to change the For Next loop so that it attempts to draw data only until the final entry. Right now I have it set to go a hundred or so cells further than I need so that I wouldn't have to update the code as often when I input new data to the data sheet (or at least that was the thought).  Here is my code:

```
Sub LRearTest()
   Dim R As Integer
   Dim j As Integer

      For j = 89 To 250
          For R = 1 To 300

           If Worksheets("Input").Cells(j, 22).Value >= Worksheets("1036L").Cells(R, 5).Value And Worksheets("Input").Cells(j, 22).Value <= Worksheets("1036L").Cells(R, 6).Value Then
         Worksheets("Input").Cells(j, 20).Value = Worksheets("1036L").Cells(R, 3).Value

          End If
       Next R
    Next j
End Sub
```

The problem is when I run this code it takes almost two minutes before it is over. I am not sure if it is because I have used j and r as integers or what.  Also I have a dozen of these on one module so I am not sure if that contributes. The code works like I said, it is just far too slow.  Help is greatly appreciated.

The point that I am checking is in Column V of Sheet "Input". Each of my  columns that I want to populate, F - U, use the same data in column V. The sheets that I am comparing the data in column V against are labeled as 1030L, 1030R, 1031L, 1031R, 1032L, 1032R, 1033L, 1033R, 1034L, 1034R, 1034LA, 1034RA, 1035L, 1035R, 1036L, and 1036R. The data being compared is in the same columns in every sheet. Thank you

Comment: Set the ends of the range, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba on finding the last row.  The load the whole range into an array and cycle that not the range.

Comment: reading and writing to a range are slower than doing them in the memory so use arrays. Read the whole range to an array, run your logic and change all of the values that should be changed in the array. Once done, paste the array back to the range. It will take less than a second

Comment: Does using the method in the link allow me to still use my For loop with integers? It does not seem to be working.  It took about the same amount of time to process, except this time without the desired result

Comment: Your code will only display the *last* value that matches your criteria.  Is that intended?  Or do you want the first value?  Or will there ever only be one value that matches your criteria for row in sheet "Input"?

Comment: There should only ever be one value for each. The cell that I am checking if it is in between the two values (Cells(j, 22)) is always unique. I am confused on how to incorporate arrays into this.  Do I have to eliminate my whole structure with my variables j and r? I guess I just don't really know how to do the prescribed fixes although I wish I could as they sound helpful

Comment: Maybe you need create a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub LRearTest()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim aDataParams() As String
    Dim aInput As Variant
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim InputIndex As Long
    Dim DataIndex As Long
    Dim ParamIndex As Long
    Dim MinCol As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsInput = wb.Sheets("Input")

    'Adjust the column associations for each sheet as necessary
    ReDim aDataParams(1 To 16, 1 To 3)
    aDataParams(1, 1) = "1030L":    aDataParams(1, 2) = "F"
    aDataParams(2, 1) = "1030R":    aDataParams(2, 2) = "G"
    aDataParams(3, 1) = "1031L":    aDataParams(3, 2) = "H"
    aDataParams(4, 1) = "1031R":    aDataParams(4, 2) = "I"
    aDataParams(5, 1) = "1032L":    aDataParams(5, 2) = "J"
    aDataParams(6, 1) = "1032R":    aDataParams(6, 2) = "K"
    aDataParams(7, 1) = "1033L":    aDataParams(7, 2) = "L"
    aDataParams(8, 1) = "1033R":    aDataParams(8, 2) = "M"
    aDataParams(9, 1) = "1034L":    aDataParams(9, 2) = "N"
    aDataParams(10, 1) = "1034R":   aDataParams(10, 2) = "O"
    aDataParams(11, 1) = "1034LA":  aDataParams(11, 2) = "P"
    aDataParams(12, 1) = "1034RA":  aDataParams(12, 2) = "Q"
    aDataParams(13, 1) = "1035L":   aDataParams(13, 2) = "R"
    aDataParams(14, 1) = "1035R":   aDataParams(14, 2) = "S"
    aDataParams(15, 1) = "1036L":   aDataParams(15, 2) = "T"
    aDataParams(16, 1) = "1036R":   aDataParams(16, 2) = "U"

    'Find minimum column
    MinCol = wsInput.Columns.Count
    For ParamIndex = LBound(aDataParams, 1) To UBound(aDataParams, 1)
        If wsInput.Columns(aDataParams(ParamIndex, 2)).Column < MinCol Then MinCol = wsInput.Columns(aDataParams(ParamIndex, 2)).Column
    Next ParamIndex

    'Based on minimum column, determine column indexes for each sheet/column pair
    For ParamIndex = LBound(aDataParams, 1) To UBound(aDataParams, 1)
        aDataParams(ParamIndex, 3) = wsInput.Columns(aDataParams(ParamIndex, 2)).Column - MinCol + 1
    Next ParamIndex

    With wsInput.Range("F89", wsInput.Cells(wsInput.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 89 Then
            MsgBox "No data in sheet [" & wsInput.Name & "]"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        aInput = .Value
    End With

    For ParamIndex = LBound(aDataParams, 1) To UBound(aDataParams, 1)
        'Define data sheet based on current column
        Set wsData = wb.Sheets(aDataParams(ParamIndex, 1))
        aData = wsData.Range("C1", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).Value

        For InputIndex = LBound(aInput, 1) To UBound(aInput, 1)
            For DataIndex = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
                If aInput(InputIndex, UBound(aInput, 2)) >= aData(DataIndex, 3) _
                And aInput(InputIndex, UBound(aInput, 2)) <= aData(DataIndex, 4) Then
                    aInput(InputIndex, aDataParams(ParamIndex, 3)) = aData(DataIndex, 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next DataIndex
        Next InputIndex

        Set wsData = Nothing
        Erase aData
    Next ParamIndex

    wsInput.Range("F89").Resize(UBound(aInput, 1), UBound(aInput, 2)) = aInput

    Set wb = Nothing
    Set wsInput = Nothing
    Set wsData = Nothing
    Erase aInput
    Erase aData
    Erase aDataParams

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow I will have to look at what you did here but it did exactly what I wanted to do and was lightning quick. Many thanks!

Comment: Since I have a dozen of these, will I be able to use this code for all 12 columns? Each column draws from the same row of a different sheet

Comment: You'd have to adjust the code, but yes, you should be able to use this method for all of your columns.

Comment: So I attempted to use this code for another column by changing "1036L" to "1036R" (the name of the next sheet) and by changing every "T" to "U", the next column.  VBA says that I have "Subscript Out Of Range" and highlights the beginning of the If statement within the For loops.  I don't know why that is as I didn't change anything in that line

Comment: Please edit your original question to include details about the other 12 columns.  We'll need sheet names, what column is being validated against (still using column V for that?) as well as the destination column (U is your destination) and the source data (still looking at column C in 1036R and validating against column E and F in 1036R?)

Comment: Ok I made the changes. I appreciate all of your help

Comment: @NewProgrammer See updated edit.  Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Now it is giving me a Run Time Error 9, saying that my subscript is out of range and highlighting                                                                                 
 Set wsData = wb.Sheets(aDataParams(ParamIndex, 1))      which you commented is meant to define the data sheet based on the current column.  Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it.  There was an error in my sheet naming that I fixed.  You are a lifesaver